# How do I store the output of a git command in a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What I want is to store the output of a git command (such as git status) inside a variable in a shell script. When I say output, I am talking about the text returned in the terminal on execution of a command, for example:
on doing a git status outside my repo:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I tried this:

```
var=$(git status)
```

But 'var' did not store anything.

Comment: The example output probably went to STDERR, and `var` will contain what was sent to STDOUT. You could use `2>&1` to redirect the former to the latter.

Comment: Thanks, the output in fact went to STDERR.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use:

```
var=$(git status 2>&1)
```

i.e. redirect stderr to stdout and then capture the output.

Otherwise when for error messages are written on `stderr` and your command: `var=$(git status)` is only capturing `stdout`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please provide any doc links I could study.
(I'd give you an vote-up but my low repo won't allow it.)

Comment: [Check this nice tutorial on redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)

Answer (score 3):

That message comes out on standard error, by default $(cmd) only captures standard out. You can fix by redirecting standard error to standard out - see one of the other answers. However you could use the exit code instead

- 128 for this case
- 0 if no errors.

I'd highly recommend this over trying to detect the string "fatal: Not a git repository..."

```
foo=$(git status)
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
echo $?
128
```

Additionally there is a git status --porcelain and --short which are useful for scripting.

If you're using Linux/OS X etc the full details are at [man git-status](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-status)

Comment: Thanks, this method using exit codes is what I needed exactly.

Comment: How do I check whether a git command supports exit code or not?
Because I am trying to use this approach to solve similar problem. but the command is `git worktree remove`. When I store the exit code of this command in a shell variable and print, there is nothing that is getting printed - https://stackoverflow.com/q/68409420/5347487