# git commands not respecting io redirection

Tags: git, bash, io-redirection

Some git commands are note respecting io redirection, for example `git bundle`. I suspect this is related to the underlying "plumbing" commands used. There is a nice tutorial on [IO redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html), and a similar question answered related to [git commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186162/how-do-i-store-the-output-of-a-git-command-in-a-variable). However that solution does not work for **all** git commands, eg. `git bundle`.

eg.

```
$ /usr/bin/git bundle create /tmp/backup.bundle --all >/tmp/backup.txt 2>&1
$ ls -al /tmp
-rw-rw-r--  1 myuser mygroup  4329 Jan 25 10:46 backup.bundle
-rw-rw-r--  1 myuser mygroup     0 Jan 25 10:46 backup.txt
```

However, from the command line I can see there is some interesting output:

```
$ /usr/bin/git bundle create /tmp/backup.bundle --all
Counting objects: 6, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 4.11 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

So why can't I capture this with IO redirection? Where is the output going?

Comment: So what happens when you do `/usr/bin/git bundle create /tmp/backup.bundle --all >/tmp/backup.txt 2>&1` ? It is not writing to a file and only to `stdout`?

Comment: Sorry, typo - `backup.txt` is created as an empty file, ie. no output was collected (unexpected) and nothing is printed on `stdout` or `stderr` to the terminal (as expected) @Inian

Answer (score 3):

It's going nowhere—or more precisely, Git isn't printing it in the first place.

Various Git commands have a `-v` or `--verbose` option, and a `-q` or `--quiet` option.  Verbose makes them print things like counting, compressing and writing objects.  Quiet makes them not print such things.  The *default*, however, is to examine `isatty()` results on file descriptors, and set or clear the verbose option based on the result.

This means that when you redirect the output (or use the commands from Python `subprocess` pipes), they default to quiet, or at least non-verbose.  (Quiet may suppress more than verbose turns on.)

You can sometimes capture the verbose output by adding an explicit `-v`, e.g., `git fetch -v`, but there's at least a minor bug in `git fetch` where it fails to pass the option on to some of the subcommands it runs, so this doesn't quite work for all cases (I wasted several hours on this a few weeks ago).

The `git bundle` command lacks a `-v` option in the first place, so you cannot set it.  It's possible to get the verbose output by running the command via a pty, so that `isatty()` says "yes, this I/O device is a tty".  The [sh module](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/) can do this, although I have not used it myself.

Comment: Interesting, `git -v ...` produces: `Unknown option: -v
usage: git [--version] [--help] ...`, and using `git --verbose ...` produces: `Unknown option: --verbose
usage: git [--version] [--help] ...`... I'm not finding a verbose option that works for my command line `git -C "${dir}" bundle create "${dest}" --all`. So inconsistent and complex... Perhaps its just my version: git version 2.1.0

Comment: Oops, bad implied bit on my part: it's not `git -v` but `git clone -v`, `git fetch -v`, and so on. `git bundle` appears not to have `-v` at all. It might be nice if this *were* a front-end option (a la `-C path` for instance) that copied it to an environment variable: that would fix the bug with `git fetch -v` that I ran into, for instance. But it's not.

Answer (score 0):

`git bundle` prints its output to stderr stream. But it only does so if the stderr stream is a TTY, i. e. an interactive console basically. If it is not, but some pipe or file, then nothing is printed as you observed it.

You can trick this check by using the `script` utility that records a terminal session or command to a file. So in your case do

```
script --return --command '/usr/bin/git bundle create /tmp/backup.bundle --all' /tmp/backup.txt
```

And you will have the output in the file `/tmp/backup.txt`. If you then look at it you will also see why this check is there. (*Spoiler:* This is progress information that is regularly updated and overwritten, this of course does not work properly if you don't watch this in a TTY.)

**Disclaimer:** This answer works for *nix systems and also for Cygwin on Windows. I don't know about plain Git for Windows, the `script` utility might not be available there by default and you might have to search for a Windows port or equivalent or use Cygwin to do this.